# Virtualizing SDN and parsing packets in controller and switch using Python

Tags: python, virtual-machine, openflow, sdn, openvswitch

I want to virtualize each element of an SDN network (2 hosts, 1 switch and 1 controller) in different VMs. At the moment, I am not sure which controllers and switches options are good and straightforward for me.

After virtualizing the network, I want to manipulate some fields in the switch packets before they get sent to the controller (packet-in messages). Also, manipulate the controller packets before they get sent to the switch (packet-out messages). I am comfortable with python programming.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are familiar with Python, I recommend you to use RYU in order to create your software defined network. With RYU you will be able  to manipulate some fields in the switch packets before they get sent to the controller (packet-in messages) and also manipulate packets before they get sent to the switch (packet-out messages).

- Controller: https://osrg.github.io/ryu/
- Mininet (virtualized network topology): https://github.com/mininet/mininet/
- Mininet Python API: http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1topo_1_1Topo.html

Here is how to do it:

- http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/ryu/

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Yes I agree, Ryu has good for what i need from a controller. But how to get similar flexibility for a switch in Mininet?

Comment: You can use Mininet API that's written in Python. http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1topo_1_1Topo.html